# Как достать R.drawable.имя_изображения из ImageView?

Tags: android

Как достать R.drawable.имя_изображения из ImageView?

Comment: Прежде всего поясните, что в вашем понимании значит "id изображения"?

Comment: Неправильно написал. Нужно R.drawable.имя

Comment: Никак. А вообще, вам странного захотелось. Вероятно, вы не тем путём решаете задачу. Расскажите нам её, возможно чего и подскажем.

Comment: Есть 2 ImageView, содержимое которых нужно поменять местами. При этом, имена используемых ImageResource обоих не известны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Drawable d1, d2;

d1 = imageview1.getDrawable(); //получаем изображения
d2 = imageview2.getDrawable();

imageview1.setImageDrawable(d2); //вот тут уже меняем местами
imageview2.setImageDrawable(d1);
```

Answer (score 0):

У `ImageView` есть два метода: `getDrawable()` и `setImageDrawable()`. Полагаю, должно быть понятно, как это использовать в контексте вашей задачи.

Comment: Предельно, спасибо за помощь.